# Does the static folder need to be checked in in Django?

Tags: django, version-control

For static directories that are not related to my own app, but to other Django modules (at the project_name/static directory ), do they need to be checked in to version control or do they automatically generate if a Django project is checked out somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

The project-wide django static directory, `$STATIC_ROOT`, referenced by `settings.py`, should be not be in source control.  Only the static directory for each app should be in source control.

In development, static files can be served by `runserver`.

In production, the files are collected from each installed app to the single `$STATIC_ROOT` via

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/.

So you should put the static directory for any app you develop in source control, but you should treat the static directory for any third-party apps the same as any other directory for those apps.  I.e., if you install an app using pip, that will include its static directory if any.